# CakePHP how to retrieve HABTM data with conditions?

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I use CakePHP 2.2.2
I have 3 tables: restaurants, kitchens and kitchens_restaurants - join table for HABTM.

In Restaurant model I have:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Kitchen' =>
        array(
            'className'              => 'Kitchen',
            'joinTable'              => 'kitchens_restaurants',
            'foreignKey'             => 'restaurant_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'kitchen_id',
            'unique'                 => true,
            'conditions'             => '',
            'fields'                 => 'kitchen',
            'order'                  => '',
            'limit'                  => '',
            'offset'                 => '',
        ),
```

The problem is that I have separate controller for my main page in which I need to retrieve data from this models with complex conditions.

I added

```
public $uses = array('Restaurant');
```

to my main page controller and here comes the part where I need your advices.

I need to select only those restaurants where kitchen = $id.
I've tried to add

```
public function index() {   
$this->set('rests', $this->Restaurant->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('Restaurant.active' => "1", 'Kitchen.id' => "1")
)));

}
```

and I got SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'where clause' error.
Obviously I need to fetch data from "HABTM join table" but I don't know how.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TLDR:**

To retrieve data that's limited based on conditions against a [[ HABTM ]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)'s association, you need to use [[ Joins ]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

**Explanation:**

The code below follows the [[ Fat Model/Skinny Controller ]](http://bitfluxx.com/2008/01/23/cakephp-best-practices-fat-models-and-skinny-controllers.html) mantra, so the logic is mostly all in the model, and just gets called from a controller.

Note: You don't need all those HABTM parameters if you follow the [[ CakePHP conventions ]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) (which it appears you are).

The below code has not been tested (I wrote it on this site), but it should be pretty darn close and at least get you in the right direction.

**Code:**

//Restaurant model

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Kitchen');

/**
 * Returns an array of restaurants based on a kitchen id
 * @param string $kitchenId - the id of a kitchen
 * @return array of restaurants
 */
public function getRestaurantsByKitchenId($kitchenId = null) {
    if(empty($kitchenId)) return false;
    $restaurants = $this->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
             array('table' => 'kitchens_restaurants',
                'alias' => 'KitchensRestaurant',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'KitchensRestaurant.kitchen_id' => $kitchenId,
                    'KitchensRestaurant.restaurant_id = Restaurant.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'group' => 'Restaurant.id'
    ));
    return $restaurants;
}
```

//Any Controller

```
public function whateverAction($kitchenId) {
    $this->loadModel('Restaurant'); //don't need this line if in RestaurantsController
    $restaurants = $this->Restaurant->getRestaurantsByKitchenId($kitchenId);
    $this->set('restaurants', $restaurants);
}
```

Comment: Dave, thank you. Your code works very well. One little question – is it possible to select only fields that I want (e.g. I only need company name, and some other info, not all fields)? I've tried to add 'fields' => array('Restaurant.companyname') to the function getRestaurantsByKitchenId (in Restaurants model) but it doesn't cause any effect.

Comment: @user1327 - Glad to help.  Yes, you should be able to add 'fields'=>array() to the Model method.  Just put it at the same level as 'joins' (not within).  You can always use DebugKit to easily see what queries are being run, and can tweak based on that.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Now everything works as I want it to. Once again – thank you.

Comment: thanks for great answer, you saved my lot of time thanks again

Comment: Is it possible to use the method in combination with pagination?

Comment: @SvenMäurer, yes, see this answer for how to keep paginate in your model:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501849/paginate-from-within-a-model-in-cakephp/6577042#6577042

Answer (score 2):

There is a much cleaner way than the solution provided by Dave.

First you need to **set a reverse HABTM Relationship between *Restaurant* and *Kitchen* in the *Kitchen* Model.**

Than you just make a *find* for the *Kitchen* you are interested in (id = 1) and you will get the associated restaurants, using [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) for filtering by *Restaurant* fields.

```
$this->Restaurant->Kitchen->Behaviors->attach('containable'); // Enable Containable for Kitchen Model

$this->Restaurant->Kitchen->find('first', array(
    'recursive' => -1 // don't collect other data associated to Kitchen for performance purpose
    'conditions' => array('Kitchen.id' => 1),
    'contain' => array('Restaurant.active = 1')
));
```

[Source](http://devblog.springest.com/how-to-find-related-data-in-habtm-models)

Comment: What shall this represent? "$this->Restaurant->Kitchen->"

Answer (score 1):

You can not need use [join], because use have setting [ HABTM ]'s association
Kitchen model hasAndBelongsToMany Restaurant model so that you can code as bellow

```
KitchensControllers
<?php
  public function index() {
    $this->Kitchen->recursive = 0;
    $kitchens = $this->Kitchen->find('all', array('contain' => array('Restaurant')));
    $this->set('kitchens', $kitchens);
  }
?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: wont this return all the kitchens?

Comment: Yes, I think that this would return all of the kitchens. However, the code is correct for finding all of the records in Model A and showing the related HABTM records from Model B.

Comment: yes, it's return all kitchens, if you want to find with conditions you can use as bellow sample: 
$this->Kitchen->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Kitchen.id >' => '5'), 'contain' => array('Restaurant')))